# php cookie not setting on server

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie.

I have successfully set it in localhost, but when I tried it on the production site, it doesn't work

localhost code:

```
 <?php
 if (!$_COOKIE['locationid']){
    setcookie("locationid",'1',time()+604800,'http://localhost/boot/' );
 }
 echo $_COOKIE['locationid'];
```

server code:

```
 <?php
 if (!$_COOKIE['locationid']) {
     setcookie("locationid", '1', time() + 604800, "www.example.com/demo/");
 }
 echo $_COOKIE['locationid'];
```

Comment: try to change the path into `/` only. `setcookie("locationid",'1',time()+604800,"/");`

Comment: Just as an addition (besides the info given by @yivi which is all true): You also need to pay attention that no other data is sent to the browser before "setcookie" gets called. And in general that also means that there must not exist any blank line before the php opening tag (<?php)! That took me quite some time recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `setcookie` doesn't seem right.

It should be something like:

```
setcookie("locationid", '1', time() + 604800, "/demo/", "example.com");
```

The third parameter is the **path**, and you were passing both domain and path together. The **fourth** parameter is the domain, and you can set it to `example.com` without the `www` so it'll work for www and the "naked" domain.

These are all optional parameters, but take notice that setting it this way your cookie will be available when a client hits a page under "/demo/", but not on your site's root ("/").

Also, I would use `isset` to check for the cookie's existence, like this:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['locationid'])) {
```

The way you are doing it, you are liable to receive a notice for trying to access an undefined index if the cookie is not set.